# mysql update query needs to execute only one time when duplicate exist

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-limit

I have two records in table with same values. i need to **insert** a id in **only** one row. Bellow is the records in table.

[image]

i need to insert **PI123** in **first** record. for this i want to run update query. can please anyone help on this ?.

i already tried this query

```
UPDATE mowbly_pace_receipt_services 
SET id = 'PI123' 
WHERE createdat = (SELECT createdat 
                   FROM mowbly_pace_receipt_services 
                   WHERE createdat='1628500751153' 
                   LIMIT 1) 
    and code='SPI';
```

Comment: hi @NazeerShaik which mysql version do you use?

Comment: @RahulBiswas iam using mysql workbench version 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `LIMIT 1` in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE mowbly_pace_receipt_services 
SET id = 'PI123' 
WHERE createdat = '1628500751153' AND code='SPI'
LIMIT 1;
```

but this does not guarantee which of the 2 rows will be updated.
You should have a `PRIMARY KEY` column in the table, like an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id which could be used to set the order of the rows.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a3b6a6bebf795a566e92e89ade88c511).

Comment: Thank you so much @forpas. Your query was worked for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this? I'm not sure it will work or not but you can try.

UPDATE mowbly_pace_receipt_services SET id = 'PI123' WHERE createdat = (SELECT createdat FROM mowbly_pace_receipt_services WHERE createdat='1628500751153' LIMIT 1) and code= (SELECT code FROM mowbly_pace_receipt_services WHERE code ='SPI' LIMIT 1);

Comment: Thanks for the response Mujeeb. but its not worked. its giving               Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'mowbly_pace_receipt_services' for update in FROM clause